# Linked List Memory

Tags: c, memory-management, linked-list

When the first call to push is made in the intersect function below, the value of tail->next is NULL. My understanding is that the &tail->next would then be pointing to the last 4 bytes of dummy object on the stack which holds a pointer to next. Now when the head_ref is changed inside the push function aren't we changing the address that is stored inside the next variable of the dummy object? So it seems to me that dummy would always be pointing to the last element of the list, even though this correctly outputs the head of the list on execution. Could someone explain what's happening in memory on each push call? Thanks.

This problem is taken from [here](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/intersection-of-two-sorted-linked-lists/)

```
struct node* sortedIntersect(struct node* a, struct node* b)
{
    struct node dummy;
    struct node* tail = &dummy;
    dummy.next = NULL;

    while (a != NULL && b != NULL)
    {
        if (a->data == b->data)
        {
            push((&tail->next), a->data);
            tail = tail->next;
            a = a->next;
            b = b->next;
        }
        else if (a->data < b->data) /* advance the smaller list */
            a = a->next;
        else
            b = b->next;
    }
    return(dummy.next);
}

void push(struct node** head_ref, int new_data)
{
    struct node* new_node =
        (struct node*) malloc(sizeof(struct node));

    new_node->data = new_data;

    /* link the old list off the new node */
    new_node->next = (*head_ref);

    /* move the head to point to the new node */
    (*head_ref) = new_node;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dummy starts out like this:

```
______     ______
|dummy| -> |NULL|
| 0   |    |    |
-------    ------
```

After first call `push(&tail->next, a->data)`, where I'm going to assume `a->data` is `5` it will loke this (Have in mind that `tail` points to `dummy` at this point):

```
 ______    _________      _____
|dummy| -> |new_node| -> |NULL|
|  0  |    |   5    |    |    |
 -----     ---------     ------
```

Then we call `tail = tail->next;` which will cause `tail` to point to `new_node`, which is why, when we would call `push(&tail->next, a->data)` again, `new_node` number 2 would be inserted in between the old `new_node` and `NULL`

At the end we call `return dummy->next`, which is going to return the linked list with the *most recently added node on first place*. The dummy itself will be deleted as it was allocated on the stack.

The `push` function becomes much clearer, if we wrote it like this:

```
void push(struct node** head_ref, int new_data)
{
    struct node* new_node =
        (struct node*) malloc(sizeof(struct node));

    new_node->data = new_data;

    /* save old head */
    struct node* old_head = *head_ref;

    /* move the head to point to the new node */
    *head_ref = new_node;

    /* link the old list off the new node */
    new_node->next = old_head;
}
```

Comment: when you make the second call to `push(&tail->next, a->data)`, `&tail->next` holds the address of an empty node or a node that points to NULL right? So when `*head_ref = new_node` is called we are setting tail's next node to the newly created node. Wouldn't the last line of your push link it back to itself? I guess I don't understand what values `old_head` and `*head_ref` actually store.

Answer (score 0):

The first call to `push` does change the dummy's next pointer, but then `tail` is advanced to point to the element just pushed (`tail = tail->next`).  So the next `push` operates on that node's `next`, not the dummy's.